# Склеивание пакетов на java>python сокетах

Tags: java, python, сокет

Привет пиплы! 
Python сервер:

```
import socket, os
s = socket.socket()
s.bind(('0.0.0.0', 500))
s.listen(5)
while True:
    c, addr = s.accept()
    data = c.recv(1024)
    print(str(data))
```

Java клиент:

```
String data = "Test";
try (Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 5000)) {
    try (DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream())) {
        while(true){
         os.write(data.getBytes("utf-8"), 0, data.length());
        }
    }
}
```

При очень большом потоке пакетов происходит склеивание(сервер выводит "TestTe" или TestTestTest)
как это исправить?

Comment: Знаю отличную шутку про UDP, но не факт, что она до вас дойдет.

Comment: А еще знаю шутку про TCP. Если она до вас не дойдет, я повторю её снова

Comment: @AndrewGrow так как это убрать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> UDP использует простую модель передачи, без неявных «рукопожатий» для
>   обеспечения надёжности, упорядочивания или целостности данных. Таким
>   образом, UDP предоставляет ненадёжный сервис, и **датаграммы могут
>   прийти не по порядку, дублироваться или вовсе исчезнуть без следа**.
>   UDP подразумевает, что проверка ошибок и исправление либо не нужны,
>   либо должны исполняться в приложении.

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP

Отсюда следует, что вам придётся из клиента вместе с каждым символом отправлять его порядковый номер, а на сервере добавить код проверки, что номера идут подряд без разрывов, код повторного запроса потерянных пакетов, код игнорирования дублей и код упорядочивания принятых данных. Либо перейти на использование протокола TCP, который всё это реализует за вас.

Comment: а как склеивание пакетов убрать?

Comment: и сервер на tcp